# How to scrape a url using a LinkExtractor that isn't a full url?

Tags: python, html, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape all the matches for this 2013 tennis tournament:

https://www.oddsportal.com/tennis/argentina/atp-buenos-aires-2013/results/

It has two pages and I'm trying to scrape both of them. However, the HTML doesn't seem to provide the full links:

```
<div id="pagination">
  <a href="#/" x-page="1">
    <span class="arrow">|«</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#/" x-page="1">
    <span class="arrow">«</span>
  </a>
  <span class="active-page">1</span>
  <a href="#/page/2/" x-page="2">
    <span>2</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#/page/2/" x-page="2">
    <span class="arrow">»</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#/page/2/" x-page="2">
    <span class="arrow">»|</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

When I hover over the link using FireFox then I can see the full url so it's stored somewhere!

How would I go about configuring a `LinkExtractor()` to scrape both the pages?

Comment: This part is generated with JavaScript so you can't.

Comment: Looks like LinkExtractor supports relative URLs - `LinkExtractor(allow="/page/", restrict_xpaths=("//div[@id='pagination']"))` did the trick. I've got a problem elsewhere which is why it wasn't working for me...

Comment: It didn't work for me though...

Comment: Strange - I’ve got another question running where it does work in one example but not in another - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70402015/why-is-scrapy-not-following-all-rules-running-all-callbacks