# Why is Scrapy not extracting the HTML from the correct page?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have the following spider:

```
class SpiderOpTest(Spider):
    
    name = "test"
    start_urls = ["https://www.oddsportal.com/tennis/argentina/atp-buenos-aires/results/"]
    custom_settings = {
        "USER_AGENT": "*",
        "LOG_LEVEL": "WARNING",
        "DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES": {'scraper_scrapy.odds.middlewares.SeleniumMiddleware': 543},
    }
    httperror_allowed_codes = [301]

    def parse(self, response: Response):
        print(f"Parsing tournament - {response.url}")
        page_links = response.xpath("//div[@id='pagination']//a[contains(@href, '/page/')]")
        yield from response.follow_all(page_links, callback=self.parse_tournament_additional_page)

    def parse_tournament_additional_page(self, response: Response):
        print(f"Parsing tournament additional page - {response.url}")
        player_tags = response.xpath("//td[@class='name table-participant']//a")
        for pt in player_tags:
            print(pt)
```

Instead of printing the `player_tags` for the additional tournament page located at  https://www.oddsportal.com/tennis/argentina/atp-buenos-aires/results/#/page/2/ it prints the `player_tags` from the start URL at https://www.oddsportal.com/tennis/argentina/atp-buenos-aires/results/.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could explain why?

The really strange thing is that the print of `response.url` inside `parse_tournament_additional_page` outputs https://www.oddsportal.com/tennis/argentina/atp-buenos-aires/results/#/page/2/.

As key bits of the pages load via Javascript then it might be useful for me to include the Selenium middleware I'm using:

```
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
from selenium import webdriver


class SeleniumMiddleware:

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        middleware = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(middleware.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
        crawler.signals.connect(middleware.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        return middleware

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        self.driver.get(request.url)
        return HtmlResponse(
            self.driver.current_url,
            body=self.driver.page_source,
            encoding='utf-8',
            request=request,
        )

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
        options.add_argument("--headless")
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        self.driver.close()
```