# Why is same URL scraped twice instead of two different start_urls?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have the following spider:

```
class SpiderOpTest(Spider):
    
    name = "test"
    start_urls = [
        "https://www.oddsportal.com/tennis/argentina/atp-buenos-aires/results/#/page/2/",
        "https://www.oddsportal.com/tennis/argentina/atp-buenos-aires-2012/results/#/page/2/",
    ]
    custom_settings = {
        "USER_AGENT": "*",
        "LOG_LEVEL": "WARNING",
        "DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES": {'scraper_scrapy.odds.middlewares.SeleniumMiddleware': 543},
    }
    httperror_allowed_codes = [301]

    def parse(self, response):
        print(f"Parsing tournament page - {response.url}")
```

When I run it then the print output states that the first URL of `start_urls` has been scraped twice. Why is this happening?

As key bits of the pages load via Javascript then it might be useful for me to include the Selenium middleware I'm using:

```
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
from selenium import webdriver


class SeleniumMiddleware:

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        middleware = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(middleware.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
        crawler.signals.connect(middleware.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        return middleware

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        self.driver.get(request.url)
        return HtmlResponse(
            self.driver.current_url,
            body=self.driver.page_source,
            encoding='utf-8',
            request=request,
        )

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
        options.add_argument("--headless")
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        self.driver.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue seems to be on this line: `self.driver.current_url,`. The driver's URL gets set to the first URL and never gets updated. I think you should rather use `request.url` on that line:

```
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        self.driver.get(request.url)
        return HtmlResponse(
            request.url,
            body=self.driver.page_source,
            encoding='utf-8',
            request=request,
        )
```

Comment: Fantastic - thanks a million. It had been driving me crazy! I'll award the bounty as soon as SO lets me...